# How do I add a host to my permitted rails hosts dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosts

I need to dynamically add a permitted host to my Rails 6 application during runtime.

I've managed to append to `Rails.application.config.hosts` at runtime, but I'm still receiving an error `Blocked host`.
Rails appears to ignore the hosts added to `Rails.application.config.hosts` that are added outside of application.rb and initializers.

Looking at [host_authorization.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/98a57aa5f610bc66af31af409c72173cdeeb3c9e/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb), I can't see an obvious way of asking it to listen to new hosts.

#### My Reasoning:

User's can programmatically create their own 'shop' on our platform, which adds a new 'tenant' ([apartment gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment)) to our multi-tenanted application We also allow them to point their own domains to our application.

However, in order to allow traffic from their custom domain, we currently would require a manual application restart if we stick with the default whitelisted domains.

I know I could use a workaround, and just set the hosts to whitelist everything (`Rails.application.config.hosts = nil`), but we need to keep the platform secure and automated.

Answer (score 3):

The items in `config.hosts` are documented as [compared using the `===` operator](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#actiondispatch-hostauthorization), which means we may include a lambda in that array, and thus make dynamic checking possible.

For the sake of an example, let's say we're returning a global permit-list from `MyApp.all_permitted_domains`. Then in `config/application.rb` we might write:

```
config.hosts << ->(host) {
  MyApp.all_permitted_domains.include?(host)
}
```

Note however that in this case the additional processing normally performed on host authorization (such as handling port numbers, or the special case of a leading `"."`) is not included. If you need that behaviour too, review the `sanitize_hosts` method in that `host_authorization.rb` source file for how.